# Uploadify - HTML5 version File extensions not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uploadify, uploadifive

I am using uploadify HTML5 version (just brought and downloaded the latest). However my problem is to show only selected given file extensions in the popup dialog box is not working as expected, it shows all files. As far as i am concern my coding below is exactly like the demo in the website. It works fine with all the other functionality like uploading, buttontext...etc only issue is i want to show only files of given type in the popup dialog box.

```
<div id="logoqueue"></div>

          <form>
          <input id="logo" name="logo" type="file">
        <span style="font-size:9px">* JPG,PNG,GIF files only </span>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#logo').uploadifive({
                'auto'         : true,
                'method'   : 'post',
                'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
                'fileTypeExts' : '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;', 
                'fileSizeLimit' : '5MB',                
                'formData'     : {'uniqID':'67867868'},
                'queueID'      : 'logoqueue',
                'uploadScript' : '/ajax/uploadlogo.php',
                'fileTypeDesc': 'Select Image', 
                 'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Does anyone feel anything fishy here ? please note i am using the HTML 5 version not the free flash version.

Comment: I use a custom plugin that wraps both the free Flash version and the paid HTML5 version, so have both (depending on browser upload support). 
I also find that the HTML5 version has no control over the file selection filter. The Flash one works fine.

Comment: can you post your answer in detail with the plugin name/code. I think it will be useful to many people

Comment: I only meant that as a confirmation of what you found. I will have to seek permission to release the plugin as it is an in-house development I created for the company I work for (so they own all rights).

Answer (score 0):

Open your uploadifive js either minify or normal which you used, then search **input type="file"** and then add your required validation attributes like this **input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"** It would help to you. Cheer Up.

Answer (score -1):

According to the uploadify creators, the file extension filter business on the file selector is a feature of flash and will not work in the HTML5 version. Here's a link to the answer in their forums if you wanted to read it (the forums are locked down now so you can't ask anything anymore).

http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/8310/missing-filetypedesc-filetypeexts/p1

Comment: html5 version is the paid version

Comment: Why the downvote? You asked about the paid version and why the filters don't work for file types. I answered exactly that question and pointed to the official word from the creators that supported this.